# Why does this simple Facebook Javascript SDK code keep failing?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-authentication

I tried to use some code from the documentation, but it keeps giving me an error: `An error occurred. Please try again later.`  What is wrong with my code?

Relevant JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AHkXS/

Relevant HTML:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', //I changed this
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true,
          });
        };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));
      </script>
      <div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="email,user_checkins">
        Login with Facebook
      </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I think whenever i ran into this problem it was because i was testing it outside of the domain in which my APP ID was valid.

Comment: Exactly Mikey thats the answer, just realized this and found the same comment from you. Please do add your comment as the answer.

Comment: @pal4life i request you please check my answer and let me is this solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think whenever i ran into this problem it was because i was testing it outside of the domain in which my APP ID was valid.

Answer (score 2):

Below is solution for your problem step by step :) 
As I guess your code is not working because you not use javascript properly

**You can solve your problem in 4 Steps**

**Step 1**

Create a new facebook app using the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and note its **App ID/API Key**

**Step 2**

use your App ID/API Key which you note in **Step 1**

The following code will load and initialize the JavaScript SDK with all common options. Replace **YOUR_APP_ID** and **WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM** with the appropriate values. The best place to put this code is right after the opening `<body>` tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
  channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  oauth      : true,
});

// Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

**Step 3**

Create a channel.html file with the below code

```
  <?php
    $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=".$cache_expire);
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
  ?>
  <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

**Step 4**
Add an XML namespace to the `<html>` tag of your document. This is necessary for XFBML to work in earlier versions of Internet Explorer.

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

**You can read all the above in details where the almost all information is get below is the links**

1. [here you can get javascript, channel file details and other details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

***Thanks...***